# Puppet module use

Tags: puppet

Right, I've been using Puppet for approx. 4 hours so have a total n000b question.
I've downloaded and installed a puppet module using:

`puppet module install resolv_conf`

All well and good. It has installed the module into:

`/home/user/.puppet/modules/`, 
again all well and good.

The module shows up when I run `puppet module list`, which I'm guessing it's supposed to.

So my question is how do I use the module?

I get that somewhere I need to add to a manifest,

`class { 'resolv_conf':
     nameservers => ['192.168.0.254', '8.8.8.8'],
  }`

but I'm assuming that I don't add that in the

`/home/user/.puppet/modules/resolv_conf/manifests/init.pp` file.

I tried creating a folder and init.pp file here

`/etc/puppet/modules/resolv_conf/manifests`

and added the class to it, but I get

`Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Could not find declared class resolv_conf at /etc/puppet/modules/resolv_conf/manifests/init.pp:4 on node rarity.home`

So I'm a bit stumped.
Can some kind soul point me in the right direction?

Fanks :)

Comment: This is a very broad question. You're missing a lot of steps, such as setting up a puppet master and defining your $modulepath etc.
I suggest you try going through the puppet learning VM: https://puppet.com/download-learning-vm and getting some of the basics down.

Comment: Thanks @Frap. Followed this https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/puppet.html and got the master setup and the agent running on another machine and puppet is making sure that some services are running. I tested that by stopping those services then running the agent and it starts them, so it looks like puppet is running OK. It was just how to "include" the downloaded module that I don't get, and the fact it went to /home/user/.puppet rather than /etc/puppet/modules. Maybe $modulepath is what I need to look at. 
Cheers :)

Comment: In that case, I can help, answer incoming..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So by default, the `puppet module` command will download modules into a local directory.

Assuming your master is running correctly, you need to install the module into your `$modulepath`, you can find your `$modulepath` on the master by doing:

```
puppet config print modulepath
```

Which depending on your version of Puppet (I'm running v4, so if you're on v3 it may be slightly different), will return something like this:

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/vendor:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules:/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules
```

Install your module into one of those directories using the Puppet Module command like so:

```
puppet module install -i /etc/puppetlabs/code/modules
```

Now, your master will understand and be able to read to `resolv_conf` module, but you need to *apply* it to your nodes. In order to do that you need to set up [node definitions](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_node_definitions.html)

So within one of your `$modulepaths` you'll need to have a directory `manifests` containing a single manifest, `site.pp` which is called the "[main manifest](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/dirs_manifest.html)"

Inside there, create a node definition for your agent similar to the one in the example:

```
node 'www1.example.com' {
  include resolv_conf
}
```

This is the simplest set up you can have. Some further reading:

- [r10k](https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k) can automate the downloading of modules for you
- [a control repo](https://github.com/puppetlabs/control-repo) is a suggested way of laying out your puppet repo
- an [ENC](https://docs.puppet.com/guides/external_nodes.html) is a better way of classifying your nodes than using the `site.pp`

Good luck!

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, man. 
I had to start again as I got cocky and removed Puppet 3 and tried to install Puppet 4 and I broke everything. Turns out there was an issue with the module as well I think, which didn't help.
Got it working now though, so thank you very much. I'll go through the extra reading as well.